# How to party add geoetry while keeping good topology (Cat nose)

Tags: topology, geometry

I'm working on a cat-like creature for game usage so it should be low poly, good topology and animateable. I blocked out the head (basically just a subsurfed cube) and kept it low poly so far, with edge-loops going around the mouth area and the ears like you see in many tutorials for human heads. But I totally fail at the nose section. I want this part more detailed (not just a bump). Adding edgeloops is a bad option since they run through the whole head (and whole body) and add geometry where its not needed. Then I tried using inset faces around the nose-area but it seems a bad idea as well.
How would you tackle this? Many thanks!

Edit: screenshot
https://gyazo.com/8118d5009e9d276b9b8d6494ed287448
I really need more deatails around the nose, it appears important to me, get a realisic big-cat nose, with nosetrails and the seperated upper lips beeing sortof connected to the nose.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why using the inset tool is a bad idea?

Comment: hello, it would help to have some screenshots or even the file, if you don't want to share your work you can transform it a bit. Anyway you can always find tricks to increase the topology in some areas to make more details. Another solution would be to use image textures and bump or normal maps to create fake 3D details.

Comment: @Carlo: I thought the edge-flow looks totally messy, really not supporting my desired shapes ...

Comment: @moonboots: normalmap is no option at this stage as I want real geometry for the nose and upper lips

Comment: so please share your file, change the proportions if you don't want anyone to copy your original shape

Comment: @moonboots: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cpe9o4yupy78wb/helpWithNose.blend?dl=1

Comment: I don't know what type of nose you are aiming for, but it seems that inset should not be abandoned a priori: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpBoq.jpg. You clearly have to adjust some loops around the mouth to achieve good proportions. Can you better describe why are you stuck? Can you sketch the target shapes upon your base model? Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your topology is not really "low-poly", it's rather "medium-poly"  ;)   Here is a try, I think it works pretty well:

[image]

Previous version:

[image]

Comment: thanks, thats looks like a good solution. Did you encounter anything else that may be wrong with that topology of the head? (its my first try at something organic ...)

Comment: it seems rather good, it also depends on your final goal, style, etc... also will you use Subdivision Surface etc? Some edge loops don't seem useful, maybe try to dissolve, if it doesn't change your shape it means that they were not useful